# Read in fractional value from stdin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stdin

I want to enter a fractional value like a/b in visual C# but I don't know how read a fractional value for user by using Console.ReadLine() command. Please help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: If all you are reading on one line is one fraction, you can use Split('/') to get the numerator and denominator as separate strings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried RegEx (and string modification)?

```
string Pattern = "\d+\/"; //Decimals, followed by a slash
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string topWS = Regex.Match(Pattern, input).Value //Will be something like 32/
string top = topWS.Value.Substring(0, topWS.Length - 1) //Will be 32
string bottom = input.Substring(topWS.Length)

Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(top) / double.Parse(bottom));
//Will return the fraction decimal value.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use `Console.Read()`
then you need to split the parameter fraction using the `/` like

```
string fraction = Console.Read();
string[] arrays = fraction.Split(new[] { '/' }, 2);
double numerator = int.Parse(arrays[0]);
double denominator = int.Parse(arrays[1]);
double x = numerator/denominator;
```

Comment: Is it really neccessary for a `new array`? Im pretty sure .NET parses `{}` as an array.

Comment: Readability is important especially for people who don't know that

Answer (score 0):

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string[] values = line.Split('/');
```

An input such as 13/64 would give you 2 strings in values. The first 13 and the second 64.